# For loops in HTML Tables (for var in var)

Tags: python, html, django, for-loop, html-table

I am trying to print some database values onto an HTML page.

The html code is run through a for loop that counts the amount of description values.

However it prints the entire database for each entry of Debit , Credit and Account Number.

I'm pretty sure the problem is inside the for loop structure , please assist.

Home.html:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">
{% extends "main/base.html"%}

{% block content%}
<h1> Kyle Database </h1>
<h2>Trial Balance</h2>

<br>
<br>

<table>
  <th>Account</th>
  <th>Description</th>
  <th>Debit</th>
  <th>Credit</th>
  {% for xAlls in xAll %}
    <tr>
     <td>{{ accountNo }}</td>
     <td>{{ description }}</td>
     <td>{{ debit }}</td>
     <td>{{ credit }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Views.py:

```
 def home(request):

    return render(request , 'main/home.html')

def Kyletrb(request):

    desc = "SELECT Description FROM [Kyle].[dbo].[_btblCbStatement] WHERE Account <> ''"

    cursor = cnxn.cursor();
    cursor.execute(desc);
    description = [tup[0] for tup in cursor.fetchall()]

    accNo = "SELECT Account FROM [Kyle].[dbo].[_btblCbStatement] WHERE Account <> ''"

    cursor.execute(accNo);
    accountNo = [tup[0] for tup in cursor.fetchall()]

    deb = "SELECT Debit FROM [Kyle].[dbo].[_btblCbStatement] WHERE Account <> ''"

    cursor.execute(deb);
    debit = [tup[0] for tup in cursor.fetchall()]

    cred = "SELECT Credit FROM [Kyle].[dbo].[_btblCbStatement] WHERE Account <> ''"

    cursor.execute(cred);
    credit = [tup[0] for tup in cursor.fetchall()]

    all = "SELECT Description, Account ,Credit,Debit FROM [Kyle].[dbo].[_btblCbStatement] WHERE Account <> ''"

    cursor.execute(all);
    xAll = [tup[0] for tup in cursor.fetchall()]

    return render(request , 'main/Kyletrb.html' , {"description":description , "accountNo":accountNo , "debit":debit , "credit":credit , "xAll":xAll})
```

Output :
[image]

Comment: Did you forget to post your Python code?

Comment: Yeah show you View and Models please.

Comment: @lewis , I have added the views , models are empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the formatting problem .

Instead of using a table, I have used 'div' tags for each column

.html :

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">
{% extends "main/base.html"%}

{% block content%}
<h1>Kyle Database Trial Balance</h1>
<br>
<div class="container">
<div class="row mb-0">

<div class="col">
<h3>Account</h3>
{% for accountNo in accountNo %}
    <p  style="font-size:10px">{{ accountNo }}</p>
{% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="col-4">
  <h3>Description</h3>
{% for description in description %}
    <p  style="font-size:10px">{{ description }}</p>
{% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="col">
<h3>Debit</h3>
{% for debit in debit %}
  <p  style="font-size:10px">{{ debit }}</p>
{% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="col">
<h3>Credit</h3>
{% for credit in credit %}
  <p  style="font-size:10px">{{ credit }}</p>
{% endfor %}
</div>

</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Output :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can make a simple query for all data at once ( as you did in the last fetch ).
I would make a list of dicts like this:

```
def Kyletrb(request):
    all = "SELECT Description, Account ,Credit,Debit FROM [Kyle].[dbo].[_btblCbStatement] WHERE Account <> ''"
    cursor.execute(all);
    xAll = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    xAll_l = []
    for row in xAll:
        rdict = {}
        rdict["Description"] = row[0]
        rdict["Account"] = row[1]
        rdict["Credit"] = row[2]
        rdict["Debit"] = row[3]
        xAll_l.append(rdict)
    return render(request , 'main/Kyletrb.html' , {"xAlls":xAll_l})
```

After that you can make a for loop in template:

```
<table>
  <th>Account</th>
  <th>Description</th>
  <th>Debit</th>
  <th>Credit</th>
  {% for xAll in xAlls %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ xAll.Description }}</td>
      <td>{{ xAll.Account }}</td>
      <td>{{ xAll.Debit }}</td>
      <td>{{ xAll.Credit }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
{% for description in description %}
  <tr>
   <td>{{ description.accountNo }}</td>
   <td>{{ description.description }}</td>
   <td>{{ description.debit }}</td>
   <td>{{ description.credit }}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: The code doesn't print at all with the above code

Comment: then use some other variable name such as  {% for des in description %} and call des.accountNo .
if that does not work the console the result and check it as per my understanding description does not contain accountNo and other properties in it .
Need to check the database query and database structure.

Comment: Hi , I have done so . It doesn't print the values at all now. I have amended the home.html code in my question so that you can see the structure

Comment: Okay .
Please have a look on the structure and try to understand it.
As per your Views.py: you have fetch all the description and pasted it in description via description = [tup[0] for tup in cursor.fetchall()] so when you applied that loop in html it only worked for description not for other properties. 
My suggestion is to make a single json then fetch all the required info in html or use for loop on numbers just like we use for array .
I hope you get my point.

Comment: if you do {% for acc in accountNo %} that will worked for account number only.
{% for dcard in debit %} word for debit card only.
you need to combine all the data or use separate loop for each property

Comment: Hi , I have done that as per the edited question. That still prints the output shown in the question as well

Comment: No No, Use separate for loop for each property. {% for description in description %} , {%for acc in accountNo %} , {% for debit in debit %} so on .

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable name in your for loop twice.

Normally it would be

```
for(description in descriptions)
```

Notice the plurality difference.

Comment: When I change that it prints the all the values in each table entry for the description as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your for loop with the following code. and I hope it will work.

```
{% for desc in description %}
  <tr>
   <td>{{ desc.accountNo }}</td>
   <td>{{ desc.description }}</td>
   <td>{{ desc.debit }}</td>
   <td>{{ desc.credit }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

and make sure that you have same objects of models given in your HTML template

Comment: I have tried that , Please see the amended question with the output and home.html code

Comment: desc = "SELECT Description FROM [Kyle].[dbo].[_btblCbStatement] WHERE Account <> ''"

Comment: I think this db command is returning no data.

Comment: Hi , the db command works if i use <div> comman , however that doesn't allow for the correct layout of the printed trial balance

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try as below.

{% for description in descriptions %}
     <tr>
         <td>{{ description.accountNo }}</td>
         <td>{{ description.description }}</td>
         <td>{{ description.debit }}</td>
         <td>{{ description.credit }}</td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```